# struts2 tokensession not setting request in Action excludedMethod

Tags: struts2, token

I'm trying to avoid double-submit problems using `tokenSession`. My action methods are working fine without `tokenSession` technique.
I add `<s:token/>` in `upsert_crypto_sources.jsp` and tokenSession interceptor in struts.xml but I receive request as null in my action excludedMethod of list().
The list page doesn't need to avoid double submit problem but if I add `<s:token/>` in `view_crypto_sources_list.jsp` and remove `list()` from excludedMethod then I always receive result `invalid.token`.
My struts.xml is like:

```
<struts>
  <package name="key-manager" namespace="/shared/km" extends="console-default" strict-method-invocation="true">
    <action name="manage_cs_*" method="{1}" class="console.shared.km.ASC_ManageCryptoProfilesAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession">
            <param name="excludeMethods">
                list, initInsert, load, delete
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
    <result name="list">/shared/km/view_crypto_sources_list.jsp</result>
    <result name="insert">/shared/km/upsert_crypto_sources.jsp</result>
    <result name="update">/shared/km/upsert_crypto_sources.jsp</result>
    <result name="load">/shared/km/upsert_crypto_sources.jsp</result>
    <allowed-methods>list, insert, load, update, delete, testConnection, forward, cancel</allowed-methods>   
</action>
```

My action implements `ServletRequestAware` interface therefore it gets the request member variable set using `setServletRequest()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a defaultStack interceptor and it is working fine:

```
<struts>
  <package name="key-manager" namespace="/shared/km" extends="console-default" strict-method-invocation="true">
    <action name="manage_cs_*" method="{1}" class="console.shared.km.ASC_ManageCryptoProfilesAction">
      <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
      <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession">
            <param name="excludeMethods">
                list, initInsert, load, delete
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
    <result name="list">/shared/km/view_crypto_sources_list.jsp</result>
    <result name="insert">/shared/km/upsert_crypto_sources.jsp</result>
    <result name="update">/shared/km/upsert_crypto_sources.jsp</result>
    <result name="load">/shared/km/upsert_crypto_sources.jsp</result>
    <allowed-methods>list, insert, load, update, delete, testConnection, forward, cancel</allowed-methods>   
</action>
```